# Hive revoke the grant err by hive.security.authorization.createtable.role.grants ( SQL Standard Based Hive Authorization )

Tags: hive

How to revoke the grant by hive.security.authorization.createtable.role.grants ?

Env:

host 172.31.10.119

port 50033

version apache-hive-2.3.5-bin

database tools

hive-site.xml

```
    <property> 
     <name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.role.grants</name>
     <value>da:select;</value> 
    </property>
    <property> 
     <name>hive.users.in.admin.role</name>
     <value>root,tools </value> 
    </property>
```

1. Start hiveserver2

   /opt/hive/hive-bin/bin/hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=50033 --hiveconf hive.server2.webui.port=10003
2. create table

```
/opt/hive/hive-bin/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://172.31.10.119:50033 -n tools
```

```
use tools;
```

```
create table test1 as select * from tools.test99 limit 10;
```

```
show grant on table tools.test1;
```

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
    | database  |    table     | partition  | column  | principal_name  | principal_type  | privilege  | grant_option  |   grant_time   | grantor  |
    +-----------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
    | tools     | test1  |            |         | da        | ROLE            | SELECT     | true          | 1565061852000  | tools    |
    +-----------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
```

2. revoke select on role da

```
set role damin;
```

```
revoke select on table tools.test1 from role da;
```

3. err log

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot find privilege Privilege [name=SELECT, columns=null] for Principal [name=da, type=ROLE] on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=tools.test1] granted by tools